# Getting text to align in a radio button template

Tags: wpf, templates, radio-button, textblock

I am attempting to make a radio button template which will look like the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MURtp.png)

And here is the template I have added:

```
<Style
        x:Key="MainWindowTemplateConfigurationWindowRadioButtonStyle"
        TargetType="RadioButton"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource MainWindowRadioButtonImageStyle}">
        <Setter
            Property="Margin"
            Value="3,3" />
        <Setter
            Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate
                    TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BRInactiveItemBackgroundBrush}" >
                        <StackPanel x:Name="Panel" Background="{StaticResource ControlsLightBorderBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    >
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ButtonText" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" Padding="7,7" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition 
                                    Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="{x:Static views:DisplayModes.SystemConfiguration}"/>
                                <Condition
                                    Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="True" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter
                                Property="Text"
                                TargetName="ButtonText"
                                Value="{StaticResource SystemConfigurationRadioButton}" />
                            <Setter
                                Property="Background"
                                TargetName="Panel"
                                Value="{StaticResource BRInactiveItemBackgroundBrush}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition 
                                    Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="{x:Static views:DisplayModes.SystemConfiguration}"/>
                                <Condition
                                    Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter
                                Property="Text"
                                TargetName="ButtonText"
                                Value="{StaticResource SystemConfigurationRadioButton}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition 
                                    Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="{x:Static views:DisplayModes.PlateSetup}"/>
                                <Condition
                                    Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="True" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter
                                Property="Text"
                                TargetName="ButtonText"
                                Value="{StaticResource PlateSetup}" />
                            <Setter
                                Property="Background"
                                TargetName="Panel"
                                Value="{StaticResource BRInactiveItemBackgroundBrush}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition 
                                    Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="{x:Static views:DisplayModes.PlateSetup}"/>
                                <Condition
                                    Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter
                                Property="Text"
                                TargetName="ButtonText"
                                Value="{StaticResource PlateSetup}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition 
                                    Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="{x:Static views:DisplayModes.ThermalCyclingProtocol}"/>
                                <Condition
                                    Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="True" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter
                                Property="Text"
                                TargetName="ButtonText"
                                Value="{StaticResource ThermalProtocol}" />
                            <Setter
                                Property="Background"
                                TargetName="Panel"
                                Value="{StaticResource BRInactiveItemBackgroundBrush}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition 
                                    Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="{x:Static views:DisplayModes.ThermalCyclingProtocol}"/>
                                <Condition
                                    Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter
                                Property="Text"
                                TargetName="ButtonText"
                                Value="{StaticResource ThermalProtocol}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition 
                                    Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="{x:Static views:DisplayModes.Reports}"/>
                                <Condition
                                    Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="True" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter
                                Property="Text"
                                TargetName="ButtonText"
                                Value="{StaticResource ReportsRadioButton}" />
                            <Setter
                                Property="Background"
                                TargetName="Panel"
                                Value="{StaticResource BRInactiveItemBackgroundBrush}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition 
                                    Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="{x:Static views:DisplayModes.Reports}"/>
                                <Condition
                                    Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter
                                Property="Text"
                                TargetName="ButtonText"
                                Value="{StaticResource ReportsRadioButton}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

However, the result I am getting is looking like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srdFt.png)

I have tried playing with all the properties between the StackPanel and the TextBlock to align the text in the center of the radio button, but when I do get that, I have a result of the text being centrally aligned, but then the content doesn't fit to fill the space of the radio button.  I can't attach any more images, since I don't have enough reputation, apologies...

which i essentially get by changing the StackPanel's VerticalAlignment to Center from Stretch, but then it doesn't fill the whole region correctly.  I am forcing the height of each RadioButton where I consume this style to be the same height of the tallest button (the one saying Thermal Cyling Protocol), and it doesn't seem like I can figure out how to make both the text be centered and fill in the extra height at the same time...

Any help would be appreciated.
Here is how I am laying out the Radio Button if it helps:

```
<Grid Margin="5,5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MainWindowTemplateConfigurationWindowRadioButtonStyle}" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ThermalCyclingProtocolButton}"
                                 Tag="{x:Static views:DisplayModes.SystemConfiguration}">
                    </RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource MainWindowTemplateConfigurationWindowRadioButtonStyle}" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ThermalCyclingProtocolButton}"
                                 Tag="{x:Static views:DisplayModes.PlateSetup}">
                    </RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource MainWindowTemplateConfigurationWindowRadioButtonStyle}" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="ThermalCyclingProtocolButton"
                                 Tag="{x:Static views:DisplayModes.ThermalCyclingProtocol}">
                    </RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource MainWindowTemplateConfigurationWindowRadioButtonStyle}" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ThermalCyclingProtocolButton}"
                                 Tag="{x:Static views:DisplayModes.Reports}">
                    </RadioButton>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the panel in the template from being a StackPanel to being a Grid.  This has now achieved the effect for which I was looking.